# Where can I find "Space policy directive 1"?

Tags: the-moon, nasa, policy

Today, as per the tabloids, President Donald Trump signed the "Space policy directive 1".   Where can I find the original/raw document?   (I get the gist from the tabloids, but wanted to read the raw document)

[The president Monday signed at the White House Space Policy Directive 1](https://www.nasa.gov/press-release/new-space-policy-directive-calls-for-human-expansion-across-solar-system)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The full text of `Space Policy Directive-1` can be found on [whitehouse.gov](https://www.whitehouse.gov/the-press-office/2017/12/11/presidential-memorandum-reinvigorating-americas-human-space-exploration) (and soon, in the [Federal Register](https://www.federalregister.gov)).

It reads:

> SUBJECT:        Reinvigorating America's Human Space Exploration Program
>
> Section 1.  Amendment to Presidential Policy Directive-4.
>
> Presidential Policy Directive-4 of June 28, 2010 (National Space Policy), is amended as follows:
>
> The paragraph beginning "Set far-reaching exploration milestones" is deleted and replaced with the following:
>
> "Lead an innovative and sustainable program of exploration with commercial and international partners to enable human expansion across the solar system and to bring back to Earth new knowledge and opportunities.  Beginning with missions beyond low-Earth orbit, the United States will lead the return of humans to the Moon for long-term exploration and utilization, followed by human missions to Mars and other destinations;".
>
> Sec. 2.  General Provisions.  (a)  Nothing in this memorandum shall be construed to impair or otherwise affect:
>
> (i)   the authority granted by law to an executive department or agency, or the head thereof; or
>
> (ii)  the functions of the Director of the Office of Management and Budget relating to budgetary, administrative, or legislative proposals.
>
> (b)  This memorandum shall be implemented consistent with applicable law and subject to the availability of appropriations.
>
> (c)  This memorandum is not intended to, and does not, create any right or benefit, substantive or procedural, enforceable at law or in equity by any party against the United States, its departments, agencies, or entities, its officers, employees, or agents, or any other person.
>
> (d)  This memorandum shall be published in the Federal Register.
>
> Donald J. Trump

Comment: What is a realisitic destination for human missons other than the Moon and Mars? Some bodies of the asteroid belt closer to Earth?

Comment: @Uwe presumably that or a Near Earth Asteroid with a low required Characteristic Energy to reach. Extremely vague.